# FizzBuzz Program Output in form of table

Tags: ruby, tabular

I have written the logic for the program to perform FizzBuzz operations:

## fizzbuzz

```
module FizzBuzz
  class Operation
    def input
      puts 'Enter a number upto which Fizz/Buzz needs to be printed'
      num = gets.chomp.to_i
      fizzbuzz_function(num)
    end

    def fizzbuzz_function(num)
      for i in 1..num
        if i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0
          puts 'FizzBuzz'
        elsif i % 3 == 0
          puts 'Fizz'
        elsif i % 5 == 0
          puts 'Buzz'
        else
          puts i
        end
      end
    end
end
  res = Operation.new
  res.input
end
```

But I am trying to print the output in form of a table.

Comment: How would that table look like? What have you tried so far? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: An helpful tool could be https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-rjust, but as Stefan pointed, how's the table?

Answer (score 0):

Here is FizzBuzz in form of a table:

```
def fizzbuzz_gen(num)
  Enumerator.new do |y|
    (1..num).each do |i|
      if i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0
        y << 'FizzBuzz'
      elsif i % 3 == 0
        y << 'Fizz'
      elsif i % 5 == 0
        y << 'Buzz'
      else
        y << i.to_s
      end
    end
  end
end

def fill_to_width(width, e)
  result = ""
  future_length = -1
  while result.length + future_length < width
    result << e.next
    result << " "
    future_length = e.peek.length
  end
  result.center(width)
end

def format_table(num)
  fb = fizzbuzz_gen(num)
  begin
    puts fill_to_width(75, fb)
    puts fill_to_width(75, fb)
    loop do
      puts "%10s%s%31s%s" % ["", fill_to_width(12, fb), "", fill_to_width(12, fb)]
    end
  rescue StopIteration
  end
end

format_table(100)
```

There may be less numbers output than specified, in order for one leg not to be shorter than another.